# How to show chosen option | Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm fetching data from an API as an options in Material UI Autocomplete, the options fetched correctly but the problem is when I choose an option and send it back to the API (POST) the option (category) doesn't show as a text it shows as a number (0) as shown in the image below (Mongodb)
[image]

```
        import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
    import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
    
    export default function Write() {
    
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState("");
    
        const handlerSubmit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const newPost = {
                username: user.username,
                title,
                categories,
            } if (file) {

            try {
                
            } catch (err) {

            }
        }
        try {
            const res = await axios.post("/posts", newPost);
            
        } catch (err) {

        }

           }
           
                 useEffect(() => {
            const getCats = async () => {
              const res = await axios.get("/categories");
              setCategories(res.data);
            };
            getCats();
          }, []);
      
      return (
      <div className='write'>
      <form className="writeForm" onSubmit={handlerSubmit}>
                          <input
                        className="writeTitleInput"
                        required
                        type="text"  
                        placeholder="title"  
                        autoFocus={true}
                        onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}>
                        </input>
                        
                                <Autocomplete
                                multiple
                                limitTags={3}
                                id="tags-standard"
                                options={categories}
                                getOptionLabel={option => (option.name ? option.name : "")}
                                onChange={(e) => setCategories(e.target.value)} 
                                renderInput={(params) => (
                                <TextField
                                   {...params}
                                    variant="standard"
                                    label="Multiple values"
                                    placeholder="Choose a Category"
                                />
                                )}
                    />
                    
                    <button className="writeSubmitButton" type="submit">Publish</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    
      )
    }
```

The question is how to show the chosen option as a string not array?

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/), the signature of `onChange` for `Autocomplete` is

```
function(
  event: React.SyntheticEvent,
  value: T | Array<T>,
  reason: string,
  details?: string) => void
```

You are expecting the value to be in `event`, when in fact, it's in `value`. Modify your `onChange` callback to something like the following:

```
onChange={(_, value) => setCategories(value)}
```

`value` may not be in the shape your API expects, so you should try using `console.log` in the callback to determine its shape and then modify the above appropriately.

`value` is `Array<T>` when `multiple` is set, so you should probably also have your default for `categories` set to the same type, i.e. an empty array (`[]`) instead of an empty string (`""`).